# jquery .contains() syntax odd error

Tags: jquery, syntax

I have an odd error happening in jquery.

When I got to: http://www.autopartscenter.net/

I get a .js error when trying to do a search

However, if I go to http://www.autopartscenter.net/home (which is the exact same page) the search works fine.

I've narrowed down the culprit jquery causing it to break: http://www.autopartscenter.net/assets/js/common.js

```
$('#ddlMake option:contains(' + make[1] + ')').attr('selected', true);
```

It seems to be some sort of syntax error.

Any help would be great!

Comment: No syntax error, syntax is fine. But `make[1]` could contain characters which screw up the selector. What is the value of `make[1]` when you get the error?

Comment: Bonus question:  If you could direct me to find an exact match, rather than contains, that would also be helpful. The GM and GMC searches trip over each other.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: - but it oddly is referencing jquery.min.js itself (which I'm using the google hosted link)

Comment: `$('#ddlMake option[value='+make[1]+']').prop('selected', true);` exact match?

Comment: @JonHarding: Yes, that means that the value of `make[1]` creates an invalid selector.

Comment: @JonHarding: The reason you get the error inside the jQuery file is because you are passing invalid data to the jQuery selector, causing the jQuery code to crash. The issue is the data passed not jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because of this

```
var make = location.pathname.split("/");
```

when you are in this page http://www.autopartscenter.net/home, make[1] is equal to 'home' while in this page http://www.autopartscenter.net make[1] is undefined that's why the following code breaks

```
$("#ddlMake option:contains(" + make[1] + ")").attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: Yep, I would agree with that.  I must have been too close to the project to see that.  Any suggestions to account for both scenarios?

Comment: I think the simplest way is just to provide a default value to use in case make[1] turns out to be undefined